# Can a single node act as publisher and subscriber alternativelye

Tags: ros, node, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write two nodes such that each node sends a message alternatively in recurrent cycle and the message contains one string message and two age variables. For example, Node 1 sends a message to Node 2 (Node 1 Publisher, Node 2 Subscriber, node 1 age ++), then after receiving the message Node 2 sends the message back to Node 1 (Node 2 Publisher, Node 1 Subscriber, node 2 age ++) and this cycle continues. I am new to ROS, please help me to design this code in python or c++.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from beginner_tutorials.msg import Num

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('custom_Chat', Num,queue_size=1
)
    rospy.init_node('custom_Node1', anonymous=True)
    msg = Num()
    msg.message = "Message sent to Node2"
    msg.age1 =0
    msg.age2=0
    msg.flag=1
    if msg.flag==1:
        msg.age2+=1
        print ("Hello! this is node 1!!")   
    rospy.loginfo(msg)
    pub.publish(msg)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

......................................................................................................................................................................

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from beginner_tutorials.msg import Num

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("Hello!this is node2")
    rospy.loginfo("I heard the message %s. %d is my age." % (data.message, data.age2))
    data.age1+=1
    data.flag=2


def listener():
    rospy.init_node('custom_Node2', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("custom_Chat", Num, callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248787/can-a-single-node-act-as-publisher-and-subscriber-alternativelye/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-25**:
What do you achieve in the end? This looks like a heartbeat implementation to see if both nodes are alive, but there are easier ways to do that.

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-25**:
I was simply trying node1 to publish a messgae on "custom_chat" topic, and node 2 to receive it, but here, node 1 is publishing it but node2 isn't receiving

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-25**:
Well, your `custom_Node1` shuts down after having done one run. You have no subscriber in there, no callback.

Basically, take the listener node, add a publisher and publish the data from the callback. This should be all. Also, I'm not quite sure if this will work with the same topic. I don't know..

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-25**:
.. if a node can "self-subscribe", so you are probably better of publishing/subscribing to different topics...

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-28**:
If possible, can you please modify the program and rewrite it for me using different topics and attach it as a link, I am getting puzzled after going midway...please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is simple (assuming there is no other publisher to this topic and you do take care of timing).

Subscribed topics get handled in callbacks, so if you publishe the first message in node 1 (e.g. from the main loop, make sure to only send it once), node 2 receives it and it is handled in the callback. In this callback, adapt what you want and publish it again, so that node 1 can receive it. There, do the same thing in the callback.

How to write publishers and subscribers is documented in detail on the wiki for [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) and [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-25**:
I am following the basic Publisher-Subscriber tutorial as given in the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CustomMessagePublisherSubscriber%28python%29).According to you, I should have line no 7-15 from talker.pyin the callback definition,in listener.py.

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-25**:
Similarly, in talker.py I should have two functions called callback and listener.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-25**:
no, just the message composition (9-11) and the publishing (15). You only can have one `init_node` per node, also you don't need the loop, but just publish once in the callback.

Yes, you need in both nodes a subscriber with a callback function and a publisher, but that does not require a ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-25**:
... special function. So, I would also recommend to rename the nodes, as both are doing "talking" and "listening".

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-25**:
Hey I have tried to write two nodes for one side communication to start with, when I am running, node 1 is publishing, but node 2 is not giving any output. Please find the code and edit if possible. I have modified the question with the two codes.